# Kendo Grid Single-Button Grid Column Menu to Show/Hide Grid Columns

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

Instead of showing a column menu on each of the columns in my grid, I want a single menu on top of the grid with which I can control show/hide of columns & freeze/unfreeze of columns.

See reference image attached to get an idea.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Kendo UI framework has kendoColumnMenu widget. 
Assuming 'grid' is a grid element, we have:
HTML (fa-... are font-awesome styles):

```
<a class="btn btn-icon grid-column-menu fa fa-columns" href="#" title="Manage columns."></a>
```

JS:

```
var $gridColumnMenuButton = $(".grid-column-menu").kendoColumnMenu({
    filterable: false,
    sortable: false,
    dataSource: grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource,
    columns: true,
    owner: grid.data("kendoGrid"),
});

$gridColumnMenuButton.on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".k-header-column-menu").click();

    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.grid-column-menu .k-header-column-menu {
height: 35px;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0; }
```

This will allow you hide/unhide columns.

Comment: There is no kendoColumnMenu widget. Are you referring to kendoMenu?
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index

Comment: according to http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-columnmenu-to-custom-toolbar-on-telerik-mvc-grid#OpG7mEgZvUWqoUwoSU0hOw this is an "undocumented" function

Answer (score 0):

First, set id to kendo grid directive: `<kendo-grid id="grid"><kendo-grid>`, precisely kendo-grid;
Second, create your own html with checkboxes or what are you want, to get the fields name is hidden or not, example:

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Id" /><span>Id</span></li> 
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Name" /><span>Name</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then get it all :

```
 var columns = JSON.stringify({
                "Id":$('#Id').is(':checked');,
                "Name": $('#Name').is(':checked');,
            });
```

Then iterate them:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    angular.forEach(columns , function (value, key) {
                        if (value) {
                            grid.showColumn(key);
                        } else {
                            grid.hideColumn(key);
                        }
                    });

/////////////////////////////////////////////
grid.showColumn("FieldName"); // by column field
grid.showColumn(1); // by column index
```

Freeze/unfreeze: just add disabled attribute to inputs